Confusion on webgl2 about format and sampler type mismatch
I am tring to implement a GPU accelerated computation with Javascript
I input the image by
const gl = this.renderer.getContext(); //this.renderer is a THREE.WebGLRenderer
this.distancesTransformFeedback.BSTextureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(this.distancesTransformFeedback.program, 'BSTexture');
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
let texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32UI, 4096, 4096, 0,gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_INT,this.paddedblendshapes);
gl.uniform1i(this.distancesTransformFeedback.BSTextureLoc, 0);

and in the shader I use
uniform highp usampler2D BSTexture;

However, it always throw the error
[.WebGL-000039AC02ED8000] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Mismatch between texture format and sampler type (signed/unsigned/float/shadow).

I consulted this answer
I have looked up OnpenGL ES 3.0.6
It says this is a valid conbination



Format
Type
Internal_Format




RGBA_INTEGER
UNSIGNED_INT
RGBAUI32



I could not figure out what's wrong

update:
I tried Firefox browser and its output implies that I am not input the texture correctly.
WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: TEXTURE_2D at unit 0 is of type FLOAT, but the shader samples as UINT.
WebGL warning: getBufferSubData: Reading from a buffer with usage other than *_READ causes pipeline stalls. Copy through a STREAM_READ buffer.

I still couldn't figure out how to fix this.

What is a WebGLRenderer? or do you mean WebGLRenderingContext? If so, then that should be a WebGL2RenderingContext

Thanks for pointing out the vagueness .It's a THREE.WebGLRenderer
